# Unreachable code in loop

Tags: java, android, loops

I am relatively a noobie and have been searching in and out to try and figure out what is wrong with my code. It is for a basic listview that will be broken down into sublist's

```
   ListView localListView = (ListView)findViewById(2131361899);
    localListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 2130903117, arrayOfString));
    localListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
//Start//
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong)
      {
        String str = ((TextView)paramView).getText().toString();
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230721)))
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Foreword.class));
        while (true)
        {return;
        //The Error starts here//
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230723)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter1Section.class));
          continue;
        }
          //And ends here//
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230728)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter2Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230745)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter3Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230752)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter4Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230759)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter5Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230764)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter6Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230765)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter7Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230768)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter8Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230778)))
        {
          ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Chapter9Section.class));
          continue;
        }
        if (!str.equalsIgnoreCase(ChapterList.this.getResources().getString(2131230722)))
          continue;
        ChapterList.this.startActivity(new Intent(ChapterList.this, Appendix.class));
        }
      }
```

Comment: This code is desperately begging for some refactoring. Anytime you've got long blocks of code that repeats everything except one or two little bits, you should consider a loop and some kind of data structure to list the differences for each iteration.

Comment: Sure, but "how can I do this cleaner" was not the question. =]  For the beginner, it is a prerequisite for them to just understand the basics of program flow, assignment, etc, before issues of style and cleanliness can really be comprehended meaningfully.

Answer (score 1):

The code after the `return;` statement will not be reached.
Inside the while loop block, each statement is evaluated one at a time.
However when the `return;` statement is evaluated, the entire method "returns" control to the calling method and no more code will be executed in that method.

Comment: Additionally the last line in the last if statement will have the same problem. `continue;` will be the last line of code executed so the line after it will never be executed.